# Codeigniter sql statement error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am tring to validate that there is a record for a name on a csv file. I am using an sql statement to look to see if that name exist, but i get this error

```
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'aa' in 'where clause'

SELECT name FROM company WHERE name =aa


 public function findCompany($company){
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT name FROM companyWHERE name =".$company);
    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Could it be an isue with attaching a variable to the end of the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
function findCompany($company){
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT name FROM company WHERE name = '$company' ");
    $result = $query->result_array();

    if($result > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

Error is

```
SELECT name FROM companyWHERE 
                       ^^^
```

---

And check wrapping `"` always ..

Comment: That seemed to work for the cases I tried. What do the ' ' do differently?

Comment: its to indicate text value

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql

Comment: `if($result > 0)` how can you compare this..can you explain??

Comment: @Hekmat that used to find out is there is an array. if its not empty array it will pass true. if false it's and empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this..

```
 function findCompany($company){
    $this->db->select('name');
    $this->db->where('name',$company);
    $query = $this->db->get('company');

    if($query->num_rows > 0) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than missing the quotes, you're also open for SQL injection. Instead of worrying about quotes, let Codeigniter/mysqli take care of it for you by passing it through as an argument.

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT name FROM company WHERE name = ?", array($company));
```